# else wont work with 'document.getElementById()'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to get the else statement to appear like the if, i can only get it to work on an 'alert()'.

```
<nav></nav>
<img src="img/lion-white.svg" alt="logo" width="300px" />
<h1 id="intro" class="animated fadeInLeftBig">How many fingers am I holding up?</h1>
<input id="answer" type="value" placeholder="how many?"/><br/>
<button id="myButton">Submit</button>
<h1 id="right"></h1>
<h1 id="wrong"></h1>
```

JS code:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick=function() {
    var x = Math.random();

    x = 6*x;
    x = Math.floor(x);

    if (x==document.getElementById("answer").value) {
        document.getElementById("right").innerHTML="<h1>YOU'RE GOOD!</h1><h2>Thanks for playing!</h2>";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML="<h1>That's wrong! My number was</h1> "+x);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the javascript console shows up? Is there a runtime error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the **SYNTAX ERROR** highlighted in the code below:

```
} else {
    document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = "<h1>That's wrong! My number was</h1> " + x);
    //                                                                                     ^^
}
```

Check the Code without errors:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function() {

    var x = Math.random();
    x *= 6;
    x = Math.floor(x);

    if (x === parseInt(document.getElementById("answer").value, 10)) {
        //  ^ ^^^^^^^^^                                         ^^
        // parseInt will convert the string value in the integer and can be compared with the integer x

        document.getElementById("right").innerHTML = "<h1>YOU'RE GOOD!</h1><h2>Thanks for playing!</h2>";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = "<h1>That's wrong! My number was</h1> " + x;
    }
};
```

Comment: Only one of the things you "highlighted" is a syntax error.

Comment: @FelixKling Right! Updated

Comment: You should also explain why you added `parseInt`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error  ( you have '**)**' that you don't need in the end of the line)

```
document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML="<h1>That's wrong! My number was</h1> "+x);
```

You need to fix to

```
document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML="<h1>That's wrong! My number was</h1> "+x;"
```

Next time you should use web developers tools (F12 , firebug, etc.) so you'll see console errors.